# Show that the series is convergent if $0 < x < 1/2$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, fibonacci-numbers

Show that the series is convergent if $0 < x < 1/2$

Series is $1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3+5x^4+8x^5+...= \frac{1}{1-x-x^2} $

So this is fibonacci coefficients times power series.

I tried to ratio test for convergence and simply got $-1<x<1$ and then reasoned that $0 < x < 1/2$ was inside of that interval

Grader marked me wrong and said I needed to review the theory, so I'm wondering what is the correct method to proving the interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio test should give you convergence only up to $\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{2}$.

Comment: How can I go about doing the ratio test correctly, like what should my $\sum$ look like?